# Vue recursive component causing Bootstrap's collapse to jump

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

I have a Vue.js project and I am using Bootstrap's collapse on a recursive component. The collapse works ok but it is jumpy and not smooth, it was suggested online that padding could be the issue, but I removed all styling and the problem still persists.

Edit: I have found out that the problem is being caused by the amount of children in the recursion. If there is 1 child, the animation is still smooth, but if there is more than 1 child, then it will jump over all of the children past the first one.

What is the best way of handling this?

Demo: http://grabilla.com/0a50a-342e7df2-bad8-4c57-9c10-92aad292396f.html

```css
.media-buttons {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.media-comment {
    font-size: 15px;
}

.media-heading{
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<template>
    <div class="media">
        <img class="mr-3 comments-img" src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="Generic placeholder image">
        <div class="media-body">
            <h6 class="media-heading">{{firstName + " " + lastName}}<small><i> {{GetDateFromNow(dateTime)}}</i></small></h6>
            <div class="media-comment">{{ commentBody }}</div>
            <div class="media-buttons">
                <a href="javascript:;" class="badge badge-primary-light"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i> 32</a>
                <a href="javascript:;" class="badge badge-primary-light open-comments-btn" v-on:click="EmitOpenCommentsModal(reqIndex, reqId, id, commentBody, firstName, lastName, userId)"><i class="fas fa-reply"></i> Reply</a>
                <a href="javascript:;" class="badge badge-danger-light delete-comments-btn" v-on:click="EmitDeleteComment(reqIndex, commentIndex, id)" v-if="currentUser == userId"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i> Delete</a>
                <a href="javascript:;" class="badge badge-secondary-light delete-comments-btn" v-on:click="ShowReplies(mainId)" data-toggle="collapse" :data-target="`#children-${mainId}`" v-if="parentId == null && children.length"><i :id="`replies-chevron-${mainId}`" class="fas fa-chevron-circle-down rotate"></i> See Replies</a>
            </div>

            <div :id="`children-${mainId}`" class="row collapse">
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <tree-comments v-if="children.length && !maxDepthReached"
                                       v-for="child in children"
                                       :id="child.id"
                                       :main-id="mainId"
                                       :req-id="reqId"
                                       :req-index="reqIndex"
                                       :parent-id="child.parentId"
                                       :comment-index="commentIndex"
                                       :user-id="child.userId"
                                       :current-user="child.currentUser"
                                       :first-name="child.firstName"
                                       :last-name="child.lastName"
                                       :date-time="child.dateTime"
                                       :children="child.children || []"
                                       :comment-body="child.commentBody"
                                       :depth="depth + 1" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr v-if="parentId == null" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: I suggest you try using jQuery's slide animation instead, never had an issue with it, all you need to do is include jQuery and call it on an element with slideIn/slideOut

Comment: @KarimA.Wazzan Thanks for the reply, I did try this, however the solution needs to be without using 'display:none'.